# StackOverflowError problem with findall () role repository for user. populated with data.sql

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

Data is load from data.sql script for h2 database. Then I want to get all user with userRepository. I do roleRepository.findAll() but i have a stack overflow error.
I am trying to register and log in. However when I submit my registration form a stackoverflow error appears. I think the error is at the level of userRepository.findall () which returns me null while there are users in the database.

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        roleRepository.findAll().forEach(role -> roles.add(role));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        return roleRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Comment: The full stack trace might shed some light on it. Why don't you add that?

Answer (score 2):

you have a @OneToMany or @ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Role` classes

so when you call `roleRepository.findAll()` it return a list of roles, each role have one or more users, and each User have a lot of Roles and so on, this cause an infinite loop.

so to resolve this problem: you add an other layer called **dto**,  it's a design pattern to avoid stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
  public User save(User user) {
  user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
  ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
  roleRepository.findAll().forEach(role -> roles.add(role));
```

//  May be the error is here, as **roles** contains list of roles and you are setting it for one user. Iterate over roles or extract one to set it!

```
user.setRoles(roles);
return roleRepository.save(user);
}
```